# What need to use, in asterisk 13.x, instead "ast_bridged_channel()" from (asterisk 1.4.2)?

Tags: asterisk

The function `ast_bridged_channel()` (asterisk 1.4.2) is deprecated and has been removed from asterisk 13.x.

**Question:**

What need to use, in asterisk 13.x, instead `ast_bridged_channel()` from (asterisk 1.4.2)?

Answer (score 1):

1) The equivalent would be

```
ast_bridged_channel()
```

is a bit more subtle than it name suggests, but the whole channel API has changed from shared variables to methods, and may have changed again, since that.

2) The equivalent would be

```
ast_channel_bridge_peer()
```

which only returns a channel if the bridge contains 2 parties (a bridge can contain more than 2 channels now).

Answer (score 0):

You should use new audiohooks entity for any new app.